# Free PE size less than vg size?

Tags: skype

Using ubuntu 12.04,

```
$sudo vgdisplay
------------Volume group------------------
VG Name                  vol
Sysytem ID
Format                   lvm2
Metadata  Areas          1
Metadata  Sequence NO    1
VG Access                read/write
VG Status                resizable
MAX LV                   0
Cur LV                   0
Open LV                  0
Max PV                   0
Cur PV                   1
Act PV                   1
**VG Size                  111.86GiB**
PE Size                  4.00MiB
**Total PE                 28635**
Alloc PE / Size          0/0
**Free PE / Size           28635/111.86GiB**
VG UUID                  s4LcLr-fc51-KE6g-0C5L-d3Sv-diPj-7HUbhT
```

**question:**

4.00Mib * 28635 = 114.54M < 111.86Gib

why? expecting your answer! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

MiB = [mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Unit_symbol)

1 MiB = 1048576 Bytes = (1048576 / 1024) kB = 1024 kB = 1 MB

4 * 28635 = 114540 MB = (114540 / 1024) GB = 111.8555 GB

Where is the problem? :-)